# display div elements inline

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery kinetic plugin in my DOM. I use it to scroll a set of divs horizontally.
The divs scroll fine but, the items are only in one line! I'm trying to get the divs to display as line by line. Below is the HTML element hierarchy.

```
<div id="item-tab-1">
    <!-- Item List -->
    <div id="item-list-section">
        <div class="item">
             <!-- Item Price -->
             <div class="item-price">
                  <h4>25.00</h4>
             </div>

             <!-- Item Name -->
             <div class="item-name">
                  <h4>DRINK</h4>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The "Item" class element is duplicated around 100 times using a jQuery code. So at run time there can be 100s of elements according to the script. The following code is used to activate the kinetic plugin.

```
$('#item-list-section').kinetic({y:false,x:true});
```

Below is the CSS I used in the elements.

```
#item-list-section {
    width: inherit;
    height: 423px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    display: table;

}

#item-tab-1{
    cursor: move;
}


.item {
    height: 70px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 20px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(75, 75, 75);
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

How can I get this done using CSS. I'm unable to display the elements line by line bt keeping the scroll-ability effect! Float is out of the table since with the float key-word, kinetic doesn't work.

Below is an image on how it displays now.

[image]

Comment: Post it here - http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can edit it too!

Comment: Do you want to display div having .item class vertically? or You want to display horizontal scroll bar for horizontally displayed divs?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot post it in a fiddle since it has lot of code and the duplication is dependent on an ajax call!

Comment: @sagar : It doesn't matter the way the .items are displayed! it's the scrolling effect I cant get if the items are not displyed inline~!

Comment: Just remove the `overflow:hidden` and it should expand the div as wide as it needs to, then down as far as it needs to, to display all the elements inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try modifying this - 
`$('#item-list-section').kinetic({y:false,x:true});`?

I have no idea about your plugin, but it seems there is an option to 'turn on' the vertical scrolling (or maybe the vertical layout as well). Set that line as -

`$('#item-list-section').kinetic({y:true,x:false});`

**Edit:**

Modify this -

```
#item-list-section {
width: inherit;
height: 423px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
display: table;
}
```

to this -

```
#item-list-section {
width: inherit;
height: 423px;
overflow: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
display: table;
}
```

The fiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/GHcb3/

Comment: by turning off the x and turning on y will make the whole thing scroll vertically. What I want here is to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#list-item-section{ overflow: hidden }` to `#list-item-section{ overflow: scroll}`
This should show horizontal scroll bar.